# WPF Datagrid trigger row colour based on value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF application that contains a datagrid. The datagrid is bound to my object OrderBlock which contains a List of type Orders.

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding OrderBlock}"
              Name="dataGridOrdersGood" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"
```

This works fine and displays nicely in my datagrid. There is one property (StatusGood) in my List though that I would like to display as a combobox where there can be only two values, "Send" or "Hold".

If the value in the combobox is "Hold" I would like the row to turn  different colour. Ideally using a linear gradient going from silver to yellow. I have tried the code below - literally just trying to turn the row red for the moment but nothing happens. I can't see what is wrong with my code below. The trigger part is very close to the bottom of the code below. I'm new to WPF and struggling with it at the moment. The code below has mainly come from a very good post that can be found here, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/586132/WPF-DataGrid-Custommization-using-Style-and-Templa

```
    <!-- Data grid formatting Grid Row template -->
    <Style x:Key="DG_Row" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3,2,2,3"/>
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>            
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Border x:Name="DGR_Border"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Silver"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>                                
                        </Border.Background>
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical},
                                  Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter},
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}" />
                                                    <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical"
                                                        Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row},
                                                                        Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter},
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal_AlternatingRow">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#AAF0C570" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#AAFF7F00" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal_Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!-- ColorAnimation here same as Normal_AlternatingRow state -->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!-- ColorAnimation here same as Normal_AlternatingRow state -->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Border>                        
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Active}" Value="Hold">
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
             </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        </Setter>                
    </Style>
```

As always any help would be great.
Thanks
M

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Do you need to change the behaviour of the `DataGridRow`, or is it sufficient to alter the style?

If changing the row highlighting based on a property is all you need, you should be able to just use a simpler `Style`, something like this:

```
    <!-- A brush -->
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BgBrush1" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#888888"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFFFF86E"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <!-- Your row style -->
    <Style x:Key="HighlightRow" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatusGood}" Value="Hold">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BgBrush1}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

You should be able to apply the style when required in a `DataGrid` by using your style as a `StaticResource` for the `RowStyle` property:

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding OrderBlock}"
          Name="dataGridOrdersGood" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" 
          RowStyle="{StaticResource HighlightRow}" />
```

Edit:

If you want to retain the rest of your styling and use a control template, you can place your  `DataTrigger` in your `ControlTemplate.Triggers`, you'll also have to supply a `TargetName` property, to specify the element you wish the trigger to act on, so using my above brush, and your initial code:

```
<!-- Data grid formatting Grid Row template -->
<Style x:Key="DG_Row" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">        
    <Setter Property="Template">            
        <Setter.Value>
        <!-- Your code -->
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Border x:Name="DGR_Border"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <!-- Your code -->
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatusGood}" Value="Send">
                        <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BgBrush1}"/>
                     </DataTrigger>
                 </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Where `DGR_Border` is the name you had given your border with the existing gradient.

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for the reply. The row changing colour is just based on a property. Can you please tell me which setters are hiding my highlighting. How does it decide which colour are displayed and which are hidden? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, I didn't express myself particularly well, it was more that your defined `ControlTemplate` which was being used to display the control did not define the setter behaviour you needed, and I suspect it didn't contain the same elements as the default `DataGridRow`, so the coloured background was hidden/not available (I could be wrong on that). Edited.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand. So where should my DataTrigger be placed in my code above?

Comment: Inside a `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` element, inside the `<ControlTemplate>` element. So, for example I've put it beneath your existing `<Border>` declaration (edited answer slightly to reflect that change).

Comment: I have moved it beneath my </Border> declaration and put controltemplate.triggers but still nothing is happening. Not sure if its being hiden by something else

Comment: The entire `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` section from my example should work in yours, provided the field you're binding to is a valid public property called `StatusGood`, and the `StaticResource` brush exists (your could use a solid colour instead).

Comment: Magic, got there in the end =D