# WPF Datagrid row colour based on value

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to change the row color of a DataGrid based on a boolean value. I've looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580612/wpf-datagrid-trigger-row-colour-based-on-value and tried it in a similar manner (defining the style locally instead of defining it in the usercontrol's ressources), but the row background won't change when the `editable` property changes. I don't know what's wrong and would be glad to have some new things to try.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ReportSampleExaminationList}" CanUserDeleteRows="False" PreviewKeyDown="deleteRow" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            RowBackground="Wheat" AlternatingRowBackground="WhiteSmoke" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent"  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Gray">

    <DataGrid.CellStyle >
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                    Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="LightBlue" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Black" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Editable}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Editable" Binding="{Binding Editable}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Probe" Binding="{Binding SampleNumber}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take out the RowBackground and AlternatingRowBackground from the DataGrid, it works. You will have to put those into a style for the DataGrid if you want to use them.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ReportSampleExaminationList}" CanUserDeleteRows="False" PreviewKeyDown="deleteRow" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent"  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Gray">
            <DataGrid.Style>
                <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
                    <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="Wheat" />
                    <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Style>
            <DataGrid.CellStyle >
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Editable}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Editable" Binding="{Binding Editable,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Probe" Binding="{Binding SampleNumber}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect. I didn't know that I can't overwrite these properties if they are set in the control's definition.